# How to ensure of Socket sent data?

Tags: c#, .net, compact-framework, windows-ce

In .NET CF on a Windows CE 5.0 based POS device, if no connection (GPRS/WiFi) is available, when i try to connect my socket object i don't get any exceptions, even after it, when i try to send bytes to somewhere by Socket.SentTo() method i don't get any exceptions too! And even the returned value indicating the size of totally sent bytes is correct! what's the matter? how can i ensure of the health of the operations?
pieces of my code:

```
Socket m_socClient = new Socket(
  AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
IPAddress ipAdd = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.7.80");
IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ipAdd, 2415);
m_socClient.Connect(remoteEP); // No exception!

// why works?
int iSent = m_socClient.SendTo(byData, byData.Length, 
     SocketFlags.None, remoteEP);
```

Answer (score 1):

Few suggestions:

- Check the [Connected](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.connected(v=VS.71).aspx) property of the connection
- I understand SendTo is more suited for connectionless protocols, and Send() is better suited for Connection-oriented protocols like TCP.
- Send() (and I expect SendTo()) may have no effect if there is no data to send. Have you checked there is data?

Comment: i don't remember why i switched from Send() to SendTo(), however i'm using GPRS connection for my device, so it's UDP or TCP? what should be my Socket initializtion code? by the way, my sending data is correct.